# Did Facebook deprecated Game Groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This link used to work. But now I can't find any information about facebook groups nor explanation to what's happened.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups/v2.5#impl

### Are the groups gone?

Comment: They recently restructured their documentation section (once again) – I assume this page got lost somehow in that process. I filed a bug report a few days ago, to ask them where it went, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1643456475905426/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they did.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/game-groups : 
"App and Game Groups are deprecated. API access for new apps will be closed on May 1, 2016. Game and App Groups will be deprecated for all apps on October 17, 2016."

I can't find any additional information on what will happen to groups created via an app. Will they go away? Will they stay? Will admins be able to add/remove members like other groups? If anyone has answers for those questions, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: We are wondering the same thing. Does anyone have any more information on the groups themselves?